# Как выйти за пределы container?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Суть такова, у меня есть container внутри него я хочу расположить на 1 половине (6 колонок) обычный блок, а вот второй блок хочу чтобы начинался с середины как продолжение предыдущего, но вширь не ограничивался container, а продолжался до конца окна (Как он располагался бы в container-fluid). Кто-нибудь может подсказать как сделать? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы это сделать, достаточно указать `position: absolute` и ширину `100%`.

```
.second {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  right: 0;
}
```

```css
.container {
  border: solid 10px #ddd;
}

.first {
  height: 150px;
  border: solid 5px red;
}

.second {
  height: 150px;
  border: solid 5px blue;
  position: absolute !important;
  width: 50%;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="first col-6"></div>
    <div class="second col-6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: почему 100%? 50 же

Comment: @ВадимЛешкевич, ага))

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-3 col-offset-3">

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Если правильно поняла, то на ум пришел такой вариант.
Container-fluid условно делим на две части. Первая - с отступом, чтобы слева осталось пустое пространство. Вторая - до конца экрана.