# Как выйти за пределы container (но экран делится не пополам)

Tags: html, css

Есть дизайн вот такого типа (конкретно этот пример не мой, если что):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Контейнер, внутри которого блок с информацией, и справа карта, которая должна тянуться на всю ширину, начиная от блока с информацией. Я видел похожие вопросы и ответы (например - [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/786032/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B-container))

Но во всех этих решениях экран делится пополам, т.е. блок, который у меня отмечен как col-3, имеет ширину 50%, и там я понял, как сделать. А у меня он занимает не половину контейнера, а, допустим, 3 колонки (из 12). И вот тут уже проблема - с картой.

Как вобще решаются такие вопросы?

Comment: Вот такая болванка есть https://codepen.io/mytrash/pen/VwPqKMK

Comment: Не мучайтесь, используйте труд атлантов https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/

Comment: У меня не бутстрап, да пусть даже и с ним - я не понимаю, как такое сверстать. На ум приходит только высчитывать при помощи js положение блока с контентом, а карте инлайново добавлять соответствующее положение. Но ведь наверняка есть какой-то способ на чистом css?